# jQuery .change not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I receive no console messages while modifying text in the input.

```
 <script>
 $( document ).ready( function () {
      $( "#oldPassword" ).change( function() {
           console.log( "Old Password Changed!" );
      });
 });
 </script>

 <form>
    <label for="oldPassword">Old Password</label>
    <input id="oldPassword" />
    <div id="oldPasswordCheck"></div>
```

... and of course the rest of the form code.  Normally cutting the code down to such barebones reveals my problem, but not this time.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is working fine so you have a problem elsewhere

Comment: Did you actually change the focus to another element?

Comment: Just a minor FYI: you don't need the `/>` on the `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U9h4c/), you probably need the `keyup` the `change` will be triggered when focus is gone out of `input` and you probably need the event as soon as to key is pressed.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U9h4c/3/)**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $( "#oldPassword" ).keyup( function() {
        console.log( "Old Password Changed!" );
    });
});
```

Comment: Good call @Adil, I was expecting it to consider the change immediately and did not bother with testing an element change.  I will mark correct as soon as the site timer allows me to.